Pilot agricultural study terminology
What is the technical word for a single crop field trial which divided into different treatments? I have examined Field trial manual Principles, planning and Implementation of Agricultural Field Trials By Peter Kurt Hansen with staff of the Shifting Cultivation Research Sub-programme, without success
The answer is likely in Agricultural Field Experiments: Design and Analysis (Books in Soils, Plants, and the Environment) 1st Edition, but I don't have access.
In my case the crops are split between mycorrhiza inoculation versus non-inoculated crops.
To put the analytics in perspective this is famous case where ANOVA was developed by Ron Fisher where the different crop groups in the 2x2 matrix were subject to different treatment and assess where the treatment was having an impact on crop growth (Fisher 1921)
Fisher, Ronald A. (1921). ") Studies in Crop Variation. I. An Examination of the Yield of Dressed Grain from Broadbalk". Journal of Agricultural Science. 11 (2): 107–135.

Welcome to Biology.SE. As a site, we expect some evidence of an attempt to answer the question yourself, e.g. a quote and a link to your source. What did Ron Fisher call it in his famous experiment?

Thanks for the welcome, I have added references of the background reading I have performed.

There is no one word for it. The design is typically called by its statistical term of "Randomized block design". There's a good study design page that explains all this here from University of Georgia.
This is a basic statistics question - I would suggest you have a read through a text on design of statistical trials and on statistical analysis before you start anything. Graphpad Prism has a decent starter guide for analysis. If you don't get these right your whole field trial will be unusable. The pages I linked above are a start for these only, this is a very complex area and I suggest you ask your advisor about this too.
